# Developer Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

Is it allowed or possible to use the same account for two Macs/Xcode? if possible, do what I just need to do is to import the developer profile from my partner's mac?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have the developer who originally requested the certificate export their developer profile so you can import it.

Take a look at Apple's instructions [at this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/export_signing_assets.html).

You can also export the certificates through Keychain Access by selecting them, right-clicking, then clicking "Export Items..."

Comment: so the answer is Yes? That two macs can use the same account?

Comment: Yes, two Macs can use the same account provided you use a system like the one I mentioned in my answer. I have done it before.

Comment: Yep, let me know if you have issues. Basically, you request all the certificates and profiles from one Mac and then export it and import it to the other one.